# Compiled program searching for and not finding project which is part of solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I've created a commandline program which I'm compiling and executing. So far so good.

The solution consists of 2 projects. The main project and the data project (with the main project being the executeable and startup proejct and the data project handling the sql connections).

It works fine BUT: Whenever I move the .exe out of the folder it has been created in it tries to find the data project and fails to do so and thus the execution of the .exe fails.

The error message is:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or 
assembly 'Data, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or 
one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
at MyProject.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

I've never encountered this problem before as both projects are part of the same solution and in the compile folder it works.

Anyone can give me a hint as towhat could be the cause here?

*Notes: The project itself has the default settings as has the solution.*

*Also like mentioned I have never encountered such a problem before as normally I only just move the .exe and don't need to also move (separately) the .dll of the other projects. At least I never consciously encountered this problem before there. If I included external projects then yes then it was necessary to also have the .dll there if I said reference by copy. But in this case its a second project of the same solution and there I never had this before.*

Comment: Why do you need to separate the executable from the data library? Can't you just move them together?

Comment: I want to make it as easy as possible for possible replacements of the program. which means the less files one has to change/remove the better.